# Postgres view conditions pushdown does not work on join

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, query-performance

I've observe strange postgres behavior and stuck with correct query optimization.

Structure and test data:

```
CREATE table t_base(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value text
);    

SELECT *
FROM t_base;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    base_id int REFERENCES t_base(id),
    value text
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    base_id int REFERENCES t_base(id),
    value text
);

CREATE VIEW v_all AS
    SELECT
        id, base_id, value, 't1' as tname
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        id, base_id, value, 't2' as tname
    FROM t2;

CREATE TABLE t_data (
    tname text,
    t_id int
);

INSERT INTO t_base (value)
SELECT 'val' || i FROM generate_series(1, 100000) s(i);

INSERT INTO t1 (base_id, value)
SELECT i, 't1_val' || i FROM generate_series(1, 50000) s(i);

INSERT INTO t2 (base_id, value)
SELECT i, 't2_val' || i FROM generate_series(50001, 100000) s(i);

INSERT INTO t_data VALUES ('t1', 1), ('t1', 4);

INSERT INTO t_data
SELECT 't1', (random()*100)::int
FROM generate_series(1, 3000) s(i);

VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE t_base;
VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE t1;
VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE t2;
VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE t_data;
```

View `v_all` is simplified in that case, in reality I have 9 tables in it and most of them have many rows.

Now I try query it:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM v_all
WHERE tname = 't1' and id = 2;

QUERY PLAN                                                                                                        
----------------------------------- 
 Append  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.056..0.058 rows=1 loops=1)                               
   ->  Index Scan using t1_pkey on t1  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.055..0.056 rows=1 loops=1) 
         Index Cond: (id = 2)                                                                                      
 Planning time: 0.264 ms                                                                                           
 Execution time: 0.103 ms
```

Excellent! Exactly what I want:

1. Scanned only table `t1`
2. Index used

Now I want accomplish same with join:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM t_data d
    JOIN v_all v ON (v.tname = d.tname AND v.id = d.t_id);

 QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..3427.50 rows=3840 width=58) (actual time=0.058..15.649 rows=2986 loops=1)                         
   ->  Seq Scan on t_data d  (cost=0.00..44.00 rows=3000 width=7) (actual time=0.023..0.727 rows=3000 loops=1)              
   ->  Append  (cost=0.29..1.11 rows=2 width=51) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=3000)                               
         ->  Index Scan using t1_pkey on t1  (cost=0.29..0.92 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=3000) 
               Index Cond: (id = d.t_id)                                                                                    
               Filter: (d.tname = 't1'::text)                                                                               
         ->  Index Scan using t2_pkey on t2  (cost=0.15..0.19 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=3000) 
               Index Cond: (id = d.t_id)                                                                                    
               Filter: (d.tname = 't2'::text)                                                                               
 Planning time: 0.626 ms                                                                                                    
 Execution time: 16.095 ms
```

And result not I expect to be both `t1` and `t2` tables scanned to search by ID, instead of just skip that "branch" by constant which than present as `Filter: (d.tname = 't1'::text)`

I've try both postgres 10.3 and 9.4:

```
select version();
PostgreSQL 10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

**Is there some technique to teach `postgres` to not look at table in view with `UNION ALL` clause just by check constant condition first on `JOINs`?**

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95540/1)

Comment: The query is not scanning both "tables" - it's scanning the PK indexes for those tables. That's a huge difference

Comment: Thanks, I add version of postgres.
And indexes scanned until in `t_data` small amount of rows. If, f.e. there place 30000? Postgres switched to `Sec Scan`

Comment: It looks like you actually want [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

Comment: No. Actually `t1`, `t2` is some sort of derivatives but we can't make it really inherit `t_base`. And yes, I look actually fast way for back references.

Comment: I dont think the planner can pushdown non-constant terms. In this case it would need the statistics to be fully trusted. ("the t_data table contains **exactly** one distinct value for name") Statistics can never be trusted.

Comment: There speech not about statistic. I want postgres to do not look tables in view for values which can't be in that table, listed with `union all`, for that I introduce table name as static field. And postgres use it for single value.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember PostgreSQL "fixates" the execution plan after 5 executions.

This means, that if it gets it wrong or incomplete after the fifth execution it won't fix it afterwards -- until you re-initialize it.

- In the first example, PostgreSQL avoids the second table since you used constant values. There's ZERO chance it will need the other table. PostgreSQL **can** fixate the plan immediately to such case since scanning the other table is not necessary -- at all.
- In the second case, however, PostgreSQL cannot fixate the plan and exclude the second table **forever**. It may be reasonable to remove it now, but what about tomorrow or the week after? PostgreSQL cannot risk fixating an execution plan suitable for current values... that could be wrong in the future. That's why it "keeps its options open", to say it in plain English.

Anyway, such a plan is not expensive. It's just an index scan that will be executed and over in no time (today). If next week you add values for "t2" then it will make a lot of sense, and will take the necessary time to execute appropriately.

Comment: There nothing about `prepared statements` in which generic plan may be used after 5th attempt (http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/116t4ewawk/reusing-cached-prepared-statement-slow-after-5-executions).